# checkbox always return False vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to display the message "True" when i check checkbox in DatagridView  but it always display "False"  im looking for solution this is my code

```
    Try
        'opening the connection
        con.Open()
            If row.Cells(15).FormattedValue = False Then
                'store your delete query to a variable(sql)
                sql = "DELETE FROM terres WHERE id = '" _
                            & CStr(row.Cells(3).FormattedValue) & "'"
                MsgBox(row.Cells(3).FormattedValue)
                'Set your MySQL COMMANDS
                With cmd
                    .Connection = con
                    .CommandText = sql
                End With
                'Execute the Data
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            End If
        Next
        'the condition is, if the result is equals to zero
        'then the message will appear and says "No Deleted Record."
        'and if not the message will appear and says "The Record(s) has been deleted.."
        If result = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No Deleted Record.")
        Else
            MsgBox("The Record(s) has been deleted.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    'Close the connection
    con.Close()
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C#. Why did you tag it as such? Where is your checkbox in your code? Where is its value? What *is* the value when you see it in a debugger?

Comment: Can you please post the markup for the datagridview?

Comment: How i can do that im using vb 2008 @Rickjames

Comment: windows forms? asp.net?

Comment: Why dont you let a datatable and dataadapter do that for you?  All things considered, you should read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Type "Option Strict On" as the first line in your code file and then fix the errors.

Answer (score 0):

When building your DataTable/DataGridView try something like this for the check box column:

```
dtdgv.Columns.Add("Process", GetType(Boolean))
'More columns etc.
'Seriously look at table adapters and 
'make SURE they wont work for your application
'Fill dtdgv
DataGridView1.DataSource = dtdgv
DataGridView1.Refresh()
```

Then when determining whether it is checked or not something to this effect:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If row.Cells("Process").Value = True Then
        'Stuff
    End If    
Next
```

That what you're looking for?